# Transaction publication with merge publication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, merge-replication

I have a transaction publication setup on SQL Server 2014 lets call it (node A) that replicates to SQL Server 2008 (node B), then I use merge replication to synchronize changes from (A) through (B) to a SQL Server CE database on a Win CE devices because (A) doesn't support merge replication to compact framework.

The problem is that changes came from the transaction publication (A) isn't replicating through merge publication (B) into the SQL Server CE database on the Win CE device while if I change anything in (B) database, it's replicating just fine.
Am i missing anything?

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will encounter a similar issue here's what worked for me:

- Run the following on your merge publication database :

```
    EXEC sp_changemergearticle 

    @publication = 'MyPublication', 

    @article = 'MyArticle', 

    @property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 

    @value = 'true';
```

For more info about the problem read this article :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects?view=sql-server-2017